# how to insert unique data into other table by looking at the primary key in php

Tags: php, sql, web

I have two tables which are:

**retailoutlets:**

```
idretailoulets (PK), 
cities_idcities, 
Mall_idMalls, 
outletName, 
BrandId(fk).
```

**Brand:**

```
BrandId(PK), 
BrandName, 
companyURL.
```

Each brand can have multiple outlet in the retail outlet table. i already insert the brand name by sort the unique data from the outlet name then i insert to the brandname.
Now, i wanted to insert the BrandID to the retail outlets table by referring to the brand table

Can someone tell me how to deal with these? thank you

[image: in this table i wanted to put the brand id, referring the outlet name, because each brand have several outlet name and in the brand table, the id of each brand already assigned]

[in this table i wanted to put the brand id, referring the outlet name, because each brand have several outlet name and in the brand table, the id of each brand already assigned

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: check it again, i already make some changes. maybe you will understand

Comment: What do you mean by _"[in this table i wanted to put the brand id, referring the outlet name, because each brand have several outlet name and in the brand table, the id of each brand already assigned"_? You can't insert only the `brand_id` into it, you should insert a complete record (outlet). And before inserting it you have to know the `brand_id`. Or do you mean "update the outlet with the new brand id"?

Comment: yeah, i meant i wanted to update the brand id in the retail outlets by referring the brand id from brand table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can understand from your question, you filled `brand` table with unique `outletName` from `retailoutlets`

> i already insert the brand name by sort the unique data from the outlet name then i insert to the brandname

So i can imagine you did something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `brand` (BrandName)
SELECT outletName as BrandName FROM retailoutlets GROUP BY outletName
```

If so, then you just need to

```
UPDATE retailoutlets O
INNER JOIN brand B ON B.BrandName = O.outletName
SET O.BrandId = B.BrandId
```